# How can I force an output function in shiny to print out plain text?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to pass some parameters to javascript using `{{}}`. However, I cannot find an output function in Shiny that refrain to embed the reactive output into html.
In particular, I would like to avoid printing out the `<div>` tags as below

```
textOutput("test")
<div id="test" class="shiny-text-output"></div>
```

Instead I would like to pass only the value (which in this case would be an empty string).

Comment: `verbatimTextOutput("hi")` retrieves `<pre id="hi" class="shiny-text-output"></pre> ` which again has some html.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried `?sendCustomMessage()` but I couldn't find any documentation. By the way, I am using a custom template and I need to pass some values to JS attributes. I can do it with `{{variableName}}` as long as `variableName` consists of digits only.

Comment: Which JavaScript are you trying to mess with? Adding your own script or inline is easy; messing with shiny's is...not.

Comment: `<div class="progress-bar bg-green" role="progressbar" data-transitiongoal= {{myVar}} aria-valuenow="78" style="width: 0%;"></div>` I need to pass a reactive value to `myVar`. This div serves to build a sort of bar-chart, and I want the length of the bars to be reactive.

Comment: No it's just a shiny app using a custom template. I need to look into how `session` works because I have been dealing only with `output` up to now, thanks.